# How to move windows buttons to left in GTK apps in KDE plasma?

Tags: kde, gtk, plasma, window-buttons

I already have **"close,minimize,maximize:appmenu"** in /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/button-layout. still it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's `menu`, not `appmenu` (these days?)

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-decoration-layout

And it was answered thouroughly at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412195/24383

Short version:

```
# ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
[Settings]
gtk-decoration-layout=close,maximize,minimize:menu
```

I have `gtk-decoration-layout=close,maximize,minimize:icon` for some reason, not sure I changed it at some point manually or it something generated from GUI settings.